# Conversion of winform to ASP.NET, keeping progress display info

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, progress

I have a number of C# 2.0 winforms applications that I need to convert to web applications.  The processes are encapsulated in objects.  Since the processes can take some time, we update progress by passing in a control to the object's Process method, and use Application.DoEvents() when we want to provide update status.  For example:

```
    public string Process(label progressLabel)
    {
        int count=0;
        List<string> items = GetItemsToProcess();

        foreach(string item in items)
        {
            // code to process goes here
            if (count % 100 == 0)
            {
                progressLabel.Text = String.Format("Processed {0} of {1} items", count, items.Count);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to use one of these classes in a web page while making as few changes as possible.  I have removed the call to Application.DoEvents() and tried to embed the label in an UpdateProgress tab, but the label is not updated until the process completes.

What is the best way to modify these types of methods so that I can display progress in a web application (either ASP.NET or Silverlight)?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) outlines a method of using a couple of web services in conjunction with an AJAX Update panel to display the progress of a process. It might suit your needs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are now constrained by the *Client/Server* relationship your best bet will probably be to implement some sort of *AJAX* solution.  An explanation of AJAX is probably beyond the scope of an SO answer so I would recommend reading up a bit on it and seeing how it would apply to your current issue.

Two popular methods for using AJAX in an asp.net application:

- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [ASP.NET ajax tool kit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/)

I prefer jQuery for a number of reasons, but for someone new to AJAX, the built in ASP.NET stuff will probably be easier.

Google wrote a good tutorial that goes over what AJAX is and how to use it.  You can find it here:

- [code_google_ajax_tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html)

And here is a good one that is specific to using AJAX with ASP.NET:

- [asp.net_ajax_tutorials_understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)

Comment: Whilst it may be easier, at least to start to use the tool kit - particularly the update panel - I think one would be better off with jQuery because then you're much clearer about what you're doing.